# How can i use npm package qr-code-styling in node js

Tags: node.js, qr-code

I want to use npm package called `qr-code-styling` in node js because it provide so many option to make fancy and styling QR code. But currently this package can be used only on frontend because it use the `canvas` to generate qr code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@loskir/styled-qr-code-node` package in nodejs because it provides all DOM which is required by `qr-code-styling`.